# Rails: how can I access a Model from a Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a constant defined in a Model, and need access to it from within a Helper. Is there a way to do this? Example:

```
#app/models/my_model.rb
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALUE = 3

  def self.get_value
    VALUE
  end
end

#app/helpers/users_helper.rb
module UsersHelper
  VALUE_V1 = MyModel.get_value
  VALUE_V2 = MyModel::VALUE
end
```

Both VALUE_V1, and VALUE_V2 fail for me (uninitialized constant).

Comment: Post the full stacktrace of the error

Comment: You can actually use the constant directly from the model(wherever you want). Why do you want to define more constants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use top level namespace when referring a constant inside module.

So,

```
 value1 = ::MyModel.get_value
```

Also, as Vimsha commented you can use the constant directly, no need to define another constant.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up refactoring my way out of this one anyway, but I learned something new!